# Writing an ActiveRecord adapter for Immudb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, adapter

Since none currently exists, I'd like to write my own ActiveRecord adapter for the Immudb database. However, I've been searching for a while online and can't find any good resources on how to write an ActiveRecord adapter. How would you do this, or are there any links you can recommend?

Comment: I'd use a known adapter as a guide to what is needed. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb

Comment: Also you will need to intimately familiarize yourself with the way the client gem [`immudb-ruby`](https://github.com/ankane/immudb-ruby) works as well and what the rails `AbstractAdapter` provides out of the box.